# ".#[random-char-string]" being inserted at end of URLs

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, urls, mod-rewrite

I've seen this on a couple of sites now and I'm having trouble finding information about (probably because it's awkward to describe):

All internal URLs like this for example:

```
    http://www.domain.com/section/
```

Are rewriting themselves to something like this:

```
    http://www.domain.com/section/#.TvuV_pim9PI
```

Does anyone know what causes this? I'm running WP 3.3 and .htaccess is just the default:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```

My Permalink settings are set to Post name and nothing in Category and Tag base.

Answer (score 6):

Have a read of the following thread on the WordPress forum, apparently the AddThis plugin is the reason the hash tag is been appended to the URL.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/random-hashtag-strings-added-to-url-in-firefox

Comment: The AddThis plugin is most definitely the culprit. Unchecking "Track address bar shares:" in the Advanced tab solved it. FYI I'm pretty sure I remember this setting being unchecked by default.